# Content in popup dont refresh.How to make dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

Im working on site,just like facebook and now im working on likes and show who like the photo or post.Im stuck on the popup that show actualy who like the photo/post.Im using this php code :

```
foreach ($viewLikes as $name ) {
    echo $name["username"].", likes it!"."<br>";
}
```

It works well, but when I put the php code in popup like this (http://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO)

```
<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
<div class="content2" id="cnt">
    <? foreach ($viewLikes as $name ) {
        echo $name["username"].", likes it!"."<br>";
    }?>
</div>
</div>
```

The content in div stays the same and doesn't refresh. I know I must use JS or AJAX but I'm not very good at it. So if some one have another popup which will load my content or some script please share

Comment: Simple way: you can refresh your popup page every $X seconds with meta-tag in html>head section:

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="$X">

Comment: you can either do what @AlexBabak has suggested or try your hands on Ajax, with jQuery, it's that difficult to use anymore ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have your PHP return you the view likes in a JSON blob, request it with AJAX and have Javascript iterate through the data and update the page with the data it receives (this is using JQuery).

PHP:

```
echo json_encode($viewLikes);
```

Javascript:

```
setInterval( function() {
    $.get( 'yourphp.php', function() {
        $('#cnt').empty();
        for ( like in data ) {
            $('#cnt').append('<span>' + like + '</span>');
        }
    } );
}, 1000);
```

This is all off the top of my head so probably won't work straight off, but hopefully it gives you a push in the right direction.  Also intervals can be messy because they keep going and going until you say stop - but the idea here is that it will refresh the list every 1 second (the second parameter of setInterval)

Also probably worth putting a JSON.parse() on the data in the Javascript - iirc it's fine to leave it in a situation like this but it's generally good practice to parse JSON as soon as you get it, just in case there's a problem with it and you need to handle the resulting exceptions